# How to create a new method or instance for another e-mail on the MVC PHPMailer within an environment?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have two PHP Controller files `MailController` and `OrcamentoController`. The file `MailController` is for contact and `OrcamentoController` is for budget. Then I want to send to the budget e-mail. Now I want to create an instance/method on the file `Mail.php` for another e-mail:

- `App/Controllers/OrcamentoController`, observe `use App\Helpers\Mail` which comes from `Mail.php`. Also notice `public function send()` which comes from both `Mail.php` and `routes.php`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Helpers\Mail;
use Core\Controller;

class OrcamentoController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view("orcamento.php", 
        [
            "lang" => "pt-br",
            "name" => "Thiago Silva",
        ]);
    }

    public function send()
    {
        $mail = new Mail();
        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
        $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
        $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];

        $isMailSent = $mail
            ->add(
                "Orçamento – " . $_POST['assunto'],
                $_POST['mensagem'],
                $_POST['nome'],
                $_POST['email']
            )
            ->send("");

        if (!$isMailSent) 
        {
            echo $mail->getError()->getMessage();
            return;
        }

        echo "Failed send";
    }
}
```

- `App/Helpers/Mail.php`

Observe that the first class and first functions are applied to contact e-mail, then I want to create a new method or instance for budget e-mail, with PHPMailer's email and password. I can not duplicate the file `.env` which is exclusive of contact e-mail.

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use Exception;
use stdClass;

class Mail
{
    private PHPMailer $mail;
    private stdClass $data;
    private Exception $error;

    public function __construct(string $lang = "br")
    {
        $this->mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $this->data = new stdClass();
        
        $this->mail->isSMTP();
        $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $this->mail->Host = $_ENV["MAIL_HOST"];
        $this->mail->Port = $_ENV["MAIL_PORT"];
        $this->mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $this->mail->Username = $_ENV['MAIL_USER'];
        $this->mail->Password = $_ENV['MAIL_PASSWORD'];

        $this->mail->isHTML(true);
        $this->mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
        $this->mail->setLanguage($lang);
    }

    public function add(
        string $subject,
        string $body,
        string $recipientName,
        string $recipientEmail
    ): self 
    {
        $this->data->subject = $subject;
        $this->data->body = $body;
        $this->data->recipientName = $recipientName;
        $this->data->recipientEmail = $recipientEmail;

        return $this;
    }

    public function attach(string $path, string $filename): self
    {
        $this->data->attach[$path] = $filename;
        return $this;
    }

    public function send(string $fromName = "", string $fromEmail = ""): bool
    {
        $fromName = $fromName !== "" ? $fromName : $_ENV['MAIL_FROM_NAME'];
        $fromEmail = $fromEmail !== "" ? $fromEmail : $_ENV['MAIL_FROM_EMAIL'];

        try 
        {
            $this->mail->Subject = $this->data->subject;
            $this->mail->msgHTML($this->data->body);
            $this->mail->addAddress("sac@thproducoes.com");
            $this->mail->addAddress($this->data->recipientEmail, $this->data->recipientName);

            $this->mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);

            if (!empty($this->data->attach)) 
            {
                foreach ($this->data->attach as $path => $name) 
                {
                    $this->mail->addAttachment($path, $name);
                }
            }
            
            $this->mail->send();
            return true;
        } 
        
        catch (\Exception $exception) 
        {
            $this->error = $exception;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getError(): ?Exception
    {
        return $this->error;
    }
}
```

- `App/Views/orcamento.php`:

```
<form action="send" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

The another file `mail.php` also has the same form with the same action.

- `App/routes.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Source\routes;

use App\Controllers\MailController;
use App\Controllers\OrcamentoController;
use App\Controllers\PagesController;
use FastRoute\RouteCollector;

return function (RouteCollector $routes) 
{
        $routes->get('/', [PagesController::class => "index"]);
        $routes->get('/contacto', [MailController::class => "index"]);
        $routes->get('/orcamento', [OrcamentoController::class => "index"]);
        $routes->post('/send', [OrcamentoController::class => "send"]);
        $routes->post('/send', [MailController::class => "send"]);
};
```

Observe the last two lines which have the same `send` coming from `Mail.php`, `OrcamentoController` and `MailerController.php`. The `/send` comes from forms of `orcamento.php` and `mail.php`.

The e-mails related to budget should not be sent to contact e-mail, but only to budget e-mail.

Comment: So what's the actual problem?